# Deleting browser history using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I tried to make deleting web browser history app using Selenium in Python but i get this error. "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="clearBrowsingDataConfirm"]"}", I tried everything to find right Xpath command but i didnt. Thanks for your helps.

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

chrome = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")

chrome.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData")
sleep(5)
button = chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="clearBrowsingDataConfirm"]')
button.click()
sleep(10)
```

Comment: probably shadow-root stuff here... you need to execute javascript to get there... but why not just delete the browser history in your native language?  No need to go through the browser.

Comment: for sure closing the driver would help. ```chrome.close()``` or use a context manager. I think if you run a anonymous session you shouldn't have to worry about that

Comment: cards makes a good point.  Your code, as is, does not use a specific profile.  By default Selenium/Chrome will use a temporary profile that is deleted when the driver closes.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a lot of time trying to figure out the same thing, the only thing that worked for me was to completely give up on trying to access shadow-root content and use basic mouse movement automation to try to achieve this. Try the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions.action_builder import ActionBuilder # need to import this

chrome = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")

time.sleep(1)  # probably unnecessary, but just in case

chrome.set_window_size(375, 667)

time.sleep(1)  # probably unnecessary, but just in case

action = ActionBuilder(chrome)
action.pointer_action.move_to_location(390, 500)
action.pointer_action.click()
action.perform()
```

Not sure why its 390 in the move_to_location(), but it worked for me. Button is pressed, history is cleared.